# If call to a pure virtual function from destructor is UB, why can we use pure virtual desrtuctors?

Tags: c++, destructor, undefined-behavior, pure-virtual

It is known that we can use pure virtual destructors, like this:

```
struct A {
    virtual ~A() = 0;
};
A::~A() {}

struct B : A {};
```

Because the Standard says in `10.4 [class.abstract] p2`

> A pure virtual function need be defined only if called ... with (12.4 [class.dtor])

And later in `12.4 [class.dtor] p9`

> A destructor can be declared virtual (10.3) or pure virtual (10.4); if any objects of that class or any derived class are created in the program, the destructor shall be defined.

What means that the code above is perfectly valid - `A::~A` may be pure virtual, it is defined, `B::~B` implicitly calls `A::~A`.

So far, so good.
And then I read `10.4 [class.abstract] p6`:

> Member functions can be called from a constructor (or destructor) of an abstract class; the effect of making a virtual call (10.3) to a pure virtual function directly or indirectly for the object being created (or destroyed) from such a constructor (or destructor) is undefined.

But that's exactly what we do here - we call a pure virtual function `A::~A` from a destructor.

So, isn't there some kind of contradiction?

Comment: The destructor is a special case, since even if it's pure virtual, it must still have a body (per the standard). The undefined part applies to pure virtual member function (which may not have a definition).

Answer (score 3):

There is no contraction.

You call the virtual destructor of `A` from the destructor of `B`.`A` destructor is not a member of `B`.

Standard § 9.3

**Member Functions**

> Functions declared in the definition of a class, excluding those
>   declared with a friend specifier (
>   11.3 ), are called member functions of that class

The standard states that there is undefined behavior when there is a virtual call **from the abstract** class destructor/constructor (which in your case, would be class `A`) to one of it's own pure virtual member function.

> [...] Member functions can be called from a constructor (or destructor) of an **abstract** class [...];

Your quote says for destructors:

1. You can call member functions from the destructor of an abstract class
2. If you call a pure virtual method (with a virtual call) **from** the destructor of this same abstract class, there is undefined behavior.

Comment: and what if `B` would be an abstract class? then it would be UB?

Answer (score -2):

UB happens if there is a *virtual call* (10.3 [class.virtual]).

> the effect of making a virtual call (10.3) to a pure virtual function ... is undefined.

But 10.3 [class.virtual] p15 says that

> Explicit qualification with the scope operator (5.1) suppresses the virtual call mechanism.

It seems that implicit destructor call has an explicit qualification.
At least compiler definitely doesn't do a virtual call there.